# How do I get Zend Framework to use 'module specific' configurations?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

Reading the section Zend_Application_Resource_Modules in the docs here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

I noticed this:

> You can specify module-specific configuration using the module name as a prefix or sub-section in your configuration file.

using this:

```
  [production]
  news.resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
  news.resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
  news.resources.db.params.username = "webuser"
  news.resources.db.params.password = "XXXXXXX"
  news.resources.db.params.dbname = "news"
```

To me this is a good idea. But, when I simply add these prefixes to certain things I want to be specific to my modules, nothing changes.

So my question is: How do I tell Zend Framework to actually use these module specific prefixes?

Comment: Just off the bat, I would not suggest using module-specific configuration as this sounds like it is going to make things *extremely* confusing for the next guy who comes along to maintain the application. Still I voted this up, because I might be wrong.

Comment: Hey Darryl , i had found this article , it might helps http://www.amazium.com/blog/zend-framework-module-specific-config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following implementation of modules in Zend.  It allows you to use "module-specific" configuration.

```
application/config/config.ini
-----------------------------
[production]
resources.modules[] =
```

By doing this, you're telling Zend_Application that you want to use the Modules Bootstrap Resource plugin.  The Modules plugin will load a separate bootsrap class for each of your modules, excluding the default module. Therefore, you need to create a new bootstrap class for your second module.

```
application/modules/news/Bootstrap.php
-----------------------------
class News_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

   //---------------------------------------
   // Automatically load our resources
   //
   // NOTE: You don't have to add this, its
   //       just and example to show that you
   //       can customize the bootstrap
   //       process just for this module.
   public function _initModuleResourceAutoloader(){

      $this->getResourceLoader()->addResourceTypes(array(
         'modelResource' => array(
            'path' => 'models/resources',
            'namespace' => 'Resource'
         )
      ));
   }
}
```

This "News_Bootstrap" class will now be loaded and executed during the bootstrap process.

The naming convention for this file is important as the Modules Resource plugin needs to be able to find the class.  Note that you **must** name the file Bootstrap.php.

Finally, you'll notice that you're subclassing the Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap rather than Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap like you do in the main bootstrap.

Now, your module-specific configuration should work:

```
[production]
news.resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
news.resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
news.resources.db.params.username = "webuser"
news.resources.db.params.password = "XXXXXXX"
news.resources.db.params.dbname = "news"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the first thing I attempted to do before finding the module specific prefix mentioned in the docs.  The above (normal way) will execute all `_init*()` methods in all bootstraps for every module that exists regardless of the active module.  I do not want this.

Comment: Darryl, maybe you can detect what module is active, and set a flag.  Then have all _init*() methods in other bootstraps check the flag to determine if code execution should continue or not. Best

Comment: Something to keep in mind: I usually re-use models, and resources throughout my modules. For example, I may have a "news" module which allows my PR and Marketing team to add/edit articles via CMS. Say I wanted to display those articles on our home page, I would re-use a model or resource from the news module in the default module.  For this to work, I would need the Bootstrap process to execute all _init*() methods.  Best

Comment: I've discovered that your solution is the answer to my question. It's just not the behavior I wanted.  And another -1 for Zend Framework's documentation (I really hope it's fixed up for 2.0). The prefixed module based configuration options do become available in the module bootstrap only.  I'll have to look into the other solutions of detecting the active module and only bootstrapping that part.  Thanks!

Comment: For module specific configurations, you can use a separate file called module.ini inside the configs folder of your module directory. Suppose you can place module.ini file inside: application/modules/my_module/configs